# calculating variance

Tags: statistics

I have the degree of freedom and the mean. I would need to calculate the standard deviation.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: First suggestion would be to clarify your question, define where your data comes from and what it looks like. Also I'm not certain how well suited awk is for statistics, even though I'm quite fond of it for text processing. Have you considered **R**?

Comment: Or any programming language that is not exclusively for text: Ruby, Perl, Python all come standard on most Linux distros these days. Also, I am not very up on my statistics, but t-statistic is probably not a "complex mathematical task", if you have all the inputs it requires.

Comment: What's the confidence interval for your t-statistics? Not that I'm a statistician  =}

Comment: Why the script needs two data files?  What is the difference datafile1 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

Still not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but here's one attempt (using a 95% range for the t-statistic) ... I only have one file (which is the 3 elements you pasted) and it's called stats1.  I'm extracting the relevant field from the file(s) using awk, and throw it at R.

```
awk -F'>' '$1 ~/Overall/{print $2}' stats* | Rscript -e 'qt( 0.975, as.numeric (readLines ("stdin"))) '
[1]  2.940089  2.776445 12.706205
```

Answer (score 0):

Using some text-processing or data-wrangling tool in combination with a statistical package such as R certainly makes sense (in particular, you might want to use R's `t.test(VECTOR, MU)`), but `awk` is certainly up to the task and might even have certain advantages.  Anyway, I've appended a (bash) script that expects its input to have one data observation per line, and emits a line as described in the script's "help" documentation.

Here for comparison are an extract from the output using `t.test()` and a run using the script (t-test):

```
$ R
> t.test(c(1,2,3), mu=0)
    One Sample t-test
t = 3.4641, df = 2, p-value = 0.07418
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.4841377  4.4841377

$ (echo 1; echo 2; echo 3) | t-stat
3 2 0.666667 3.4641
```

```
#!/bin/bash
# USE AT YOUR OWN RISK
# For help: $0 --help
VERSION=0.1.1

# Requires: awk

BN=$(basename "$0")

function help {
cat <<EOF
Syntax: $0 [n1 [FILE]]

Compute the sample mean, the sample variance, and the t-statistic for
the array of numbers in column n1 of the input, where n1 defaults to 1,
and FILE defaults to STDIN.

The output consists of a single line of four values:

n mean variance t

where "n" is the sample size (possibly 0),
      "mean" is the sample mean,
      "variance" is the average of the squared deviations from the mean, and
      "t" is the sample t-statistic, computed as 
           mean * sqrt( n * ss / (n-1));

If a statistic cannot be computed, an asterisk (*) is used in its place.

If the value in the specified field in the input is null or
non-numeric, it is ignored.

If a file is specified as "-" then STDIN is read.

Example:

$BN <<< $'1\n2\n3'
3 2 2 3.4641

EOF
}

function die     { echo "$BN: $@" >&2 ; exit 1 ; }

case "$1" in
    -h | --help )
    help
    exit
    ;;
    -v | --verbose )
    VERBOSE=1
    shift
    ;;
esac

# Default:

file=-

if [ $# = 0 ] ; then
    f1=1
elif [ "$1" = - ] ; then
    f1=1
else
   f1="$1"
   shift
   check=`expr "$f1" : "\([0-9]*\)"`
   if [ "$f1" != "$check" ] ; then die a non-numeric field was specified ; fi
fi

if [ $# != 0 ] ; then file="$1" ; fi

awk -v verbose="$VERBOSE" -v f1="$f1" '
  BEGIN { a1=0; s1=0; n=0; }
  NF < f1 { next }
  $f1 == "" || ($f1+0 != $f1) { next }
  { n++; a1 += $f1; s1 += $f1*$f1; }

  END {
    s="*";
    if ( n == 0 ) {print 0, s, s, s; exit }
    avg = a1/n;
    var = s1/n - avg*avg;
    if (var == 0) { print n, avg, var, s; exit}
    tstat = avg * sqrt( (n-1) / var);
    print n, avg, var, tstat; 
  } ' "$file"
```